# Wordpress - Adding classes to wp_list_pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone know how to edit/change Wordpress's wp_list_pages function in order to add classes to the ul and li items?

I'm trying to implement the new version of jquery.treeview which requires `<li class="expandable">` and `<ul style="display: none;">` on expandable lists and child ul's.

I've been messing around with this but it aint working too good in that it applies the 'expandable' class to all li's:

```
$pages = wp_list_pages('title_li=&echo=0' );
        $pages = preg_replace('/class="/','class="expandable ', $pages); //note space on end of replacement string                  
        //output
        echo $pages;
```

And here is what the outputted html should look like:

```
<ul class="treeview" id="tree">

        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>           
        <li class="expandable"><a href="#">Expand 1</a>
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li class="expandable"><a href="#">Expand 2_1</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="#">Expanded 3_1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Expanded 3_2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Expanded 3_3</a></li>
                    </ul>                       
                </li>
                <li class="expandable"><a href="#" >Expand 2_2</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="#">Expanded 4_1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Expanded 4_2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Expanded 4_3</a></li>
                    </ul>  
                </li>                       
            </ul>
```

Hope this makes sense and any help greatly appreciated, S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are trying to activate a tree view on the page items. As this would require JavaScript you can simply add the class using JavaScript before initializing the tree view:

```
$("#tree li").addClass("expandable");
$("#tree").treeview();
```

If you also want to hide all ul elements you can use jQuery, too (not sure about the correct syntax):

```
$("#tree ul").hide();
```

Comment: Wow, didn't seem to do anything on the 'addClass' front but the 'hide' seems to have done the trick. Many, many thanks, S.

Comment: I usually do it this way, as a non-js user will still be able to see everything if you only hide it using js and not a class added with PHP. btw: feel free to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Plugin ([Classy wp-List](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/classy-wp-list-pages/)) helps. I haven't tried it yet but it says it will let you define a class for each page in the backend.

good luck.

Comment: ah well.. sorry. But you could add the css for the ul via jquery '$("#tree ul").addClass("hide");' and then define a css class '.hide{display:none;}'