# wp_list_pages custom parent/child attribute

Tags: wordpress

Isn't there anyway to add custom attribute and class(S)/id(S) in ul and li while using `wp_list_page`

**Google** alot for that even tried exploring **Stackoverflow**

found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194537/wordpress-adding-classes-to-wp-list-pages) ( still seems there is no way using `wp_list_page` as someone ans using jquery )

```
  <!-- navigation Menu -->

    <div class="navigation_menu">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSJ1H.png) as reputation is low can't add image ( sorry )

found this [site](http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item) that doesn't help anyway

any suggestion / help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: you can use `get_pages()` to customise html explained [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23330336/3111930

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what helped me.. none of others methods work...

```
           <?php

             global $wpdb;
    $men = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,post_parent,post_title,guid FROM `wp_posts` where post_type='page' and post_parent='0'  and post_status='publish'");
    $i=1;
    foreach($men as $menu){

        if($menu->post_parent=="0"){
            $post_prnt = '';
             '<li data-match="'.$i.'" class="" id="main_2_rptLevelOneNav_footeritem_'.$i.'">';
             '<a id="main_2_rptLevelOneNav_hypLevelTwoTitle_'.$i.'" href="'.$menu->guid.'">'.$menu->post_title.'</a>';
             '</li>';
            $post_prnt = $wpdb->get_results("select ID,post_title,guid,post_parent FROM `wp_posts` where post_parent='".$menu->ID."' and post_status='publish' and post_type='page'");
            $arr = '';
            if(count($post_prnt>0))
            {

                    $u=0;
                     foreach ($post_prnt as $p_prnt){
                    $arr[] = array($i,$p_prnt->post_title,$p_prnt->guid); 
                    $u++;
                        }
            $arrr[] = array($arr);   
            }

            $i++;
        }
    }

if(count($arrr)>0)
{
     foreach($arrr as $key=>$val)
     {
        if(count($val)>0)
        {
            foreach($val as $key1=>$val1)
            {
                if(count($val1)>0)
                {
                    if($val1[0][0]!='')
                    {
                    echo '<li data-match="'.$val1[0][0].'" class="level-one" style="display: none; left: 335.15px; top: 111px; position: absolute;"><ul>';
                        $k=0;
                        foreach($val1 as $key2=>$val2)
                        {
                            echo '<li class="level-two">
                        <a href="'.$val2[2].'" id="main_0_ctl01_rptLevelOneSubNav_rptLevelTwoSubNav_'.$val1[0][0].'_hypLevelTwoTitle_'.$k.'">'.$val2[1].'</a>
                    </li>';
                    $k++;
                        }
                    echo '</ul></li>';
                 }   
                }
            }
        }
        //foreach($val )        
     }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23330336/3111930 you need to customize the class named Walker_Page used by the wp_list_pages function call.

For the first `<ul>`-element you need to customize it like Nathan Dawson wrote.
To Customize the `<li>`-elements (typically child elements of the page currently showing) you need to customize the `function start_el` e.g.:

```
public function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0 ) {
        if ( $depth ) { // code indent
            $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        } else {
            $indent = '';
        }

        if ( '' === $page->post_title ) { // DisplayName
            $page->post_title = sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $page->ID );
        }

        $args['link_before'] = empty( $args['link_before'] ) ? '' : $args['link_before'];
        $args['link_after'] = empty( $args['link_after'] ) ? '' : $args['link_after'];

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $output .= $indent . sprintf(
            '<li class="%s"><a href="%s">%s%s%s</a>',
            'btn btn-default btn-block', // Using Bootstrap Button Layout
            get_permalink( $page->ID ), // href
            $args['link_before'], // Link Prefix
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ), // Link Text
            $args['link_after']  // Link Postfix
        );
    }
```

In this example the css classes `btn btn-default btn-block` are added to each `<li>`-items class-attribute so they are shown as bootstrap styled buttons.

Take a look at wp-includes\post-template.php to see the original start_el function. In my example the css class leveling is not included.

But you should only need to insert a `if ($depth == 0)` and customize the li with the attribute, and `if ($depth == 1)` customize it the other way. 
I mean customize the sprintf-output in this and that case you know?

Comment: in these `<li class="%s">` do i just need to edit `'btn btn-default btn-block'` for my custom class?

Comment: @TalhaHabib for changing the css class of the li yes. But this would only fit your level-two when inside if ($depth == 1). You could copy paste this part and change the level-two thing to level-one and add a data-match="0" inside the `<li>´ element. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php for syntax of the used php function.